# Sequelize hasOne with BelongsToMany

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have to models **DistrictArea** and **Order** which Order must have a DistrictArea instance in it. 
so I have done this so far:

```
Order.hasOne(models.DistricArea)
```

and in migration file I used this.

```
queryInterface.addColumn('Orders', 'district_area_id', {

        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'DistricAreas',
          key: 'id'
        }

      })
```

and I have two questions. If we use associated methods in the model , we have to explicitly define these field to our models?

```
district_area_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
```

and do I need to define **belongsTo** in another model (DistricArea)?

the second question is I didn't define any field in **DistricArea** that associated with Orders. but when I want to use query DistricArea.findAll() it comes with this error:

> "column "OrderId" does not exist"

so this is the goal I am trying to achieve:

> I need to tell we have many orders that, every order has a
>   DistricArea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you still need to define the fields in your model
2. from what you described above it should be **belongsTo** instead of **hasOne** for order model , and **hasMany** in DistricArea model and then define your sourceKey using your **district_area_id** field.

   ```
   Order.belongsTo(models.DistricArea,{foreignKey: 'district_area_id'})
   DistricArea.hasMany(models.Order, {foreignKey: 'district_area_id', sourceKey: 'id'})
   ```

after this , in DistricArea.findAll() you would get all DistricArea and then inside you will have a Order array which contain every order for each DistricArea, or in a Order.findAll() call you will see all orders with a field district_area_id

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use associated methods in the model, `Sequelize` will automatically add the foreign key to the model. However, it’s a good practice to explicitly define it.
2. Yes you have define `belongsTo` in the `Order` model. This sets up a One-To-Many relationship between `DistrictArea` and `Order`

For your Second Question: the error “column ‘OrderId’ does not exist”

When you define a One-To-Many relationship using `hasMany` and `belongsTo`, Sequelize expects to find a foreign key in the model where belongsTo is defined. To fix the error, you need to define `foreignKey` in `DistrictArea`:

```
DistrictArea.hasMany(Order, {
  foreignKey: 'district_area_id',
  sourceKey: 'id'
});
```